# sensor ACCELEROMETER does not work as expectation

Tags: android, android-sensors

below is my code for sensing motion in android :

```
senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];


        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) >= 1000) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;


            float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;
            //Log.d("DEBUG", String.valueOf(speed));
            Log.d("DEBUG",String.valueof(speed));

        }
    }
}
```

This code work properly when the screen is on. That means when screen is on i get speed value 0-4 during idle and >5 during movement. But weird thing is that when screen is off the speed value ups and downs too much like sometimes it 100 ..sometime 0 THOUGH the device is idle. I dont know why my accelerometer sensing too much while screen is off during idle. Do you have any solution for this. 
N.B my tablet is Alcatel Pixi 7; OS:lolipop . Another important thing this same code work as expected on my samsung galaxy s6. That means it give expected speed value when screen is off. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most likely problem is that the accelerometer measure frequency is lower when the screen is off. The same thing should be true for the Galaxy S6.

Comment: then why speed value is different for same condition in galaxy s6 and tablet?? @XaverKapeller

Comment: Because they are different devices. What are you calculating anyway? Whatever it is, its no speed. At least technically.

Comment: speed is just a variable. I calculate this speed value like this  
       float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime  *10000;
why it vary device to device??.google sensor documentation does not tell that it will depends on device.......@XaverKapeller

Comment: Of course it varies by device! If you buy two different cars do you expect both to have the same top speed and acceleration? No, they are going to be different, just as two different smartphones are going to perform differently.

Comment: Did you check if the frequency of sensor updates is reduced on the Pixi 7? Or maybe the Pixi 7 receives multiple sensor updates in quick succession when the device wakes up while its idle. Most likely that's what's causing your problems. And regarding the speed variable. What are you trying to calculate here? I may be able to help you if you tell me what you are trying to do.

Comment: okay my target is :i need to detect user movement. So i calculate speed. please see the code above. there you will see how i calculate it. when the device is idle(here idle mean the device isnt movement) the speed value is below 5(here 5 is just a int value) when i move the device the speed value is greater then 5. So that i can easily determine that when my device is moving or not moving by speed value. I get this value of speed when my device screen is ON but unfortunately when device screen is off the speed value UP and DOWN TOO much though the device is idle(mean not moving) @XaverKapeller

Comment: You do know there is already a software sensor which does exactly that? The significant motion sensor `Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION` triggers when the device is moved, for example by the user walking or driving in a car.